# Xamarin Consumin Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I am consuming a service in Xamarin (Visual studio proyecto PCL) ... I want to enter Infringements and for this I enter in a form .... by pressing the button "Create Infringement" this throws me the message "Successfully created infringement" when in my SQL database does not create Nothing, I put a try and a catch to see the exceptions but it does not fall anywhere, I need help please, greetings to all!

```
public partial class NewInfraccionPage : ContentPage
{
    private Usuarios usuarios;

    public NewInfraccionPage(Usuarios usuarios)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.usuarios = usuarios;    
        saveButton.Clicked += saveButton_Clicked;
    }

    private async void saveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(motivoEntry.Text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe Ingresar un Motivo de Infraccion", "Aceptar");
            motivoEntry.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(patenteEntry.Text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe Ingresar una patente", "Aceptar");
            patenteEntry.Focus();
            return;
        }


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lugarEntry.Text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe Ingresar un Lugar", "Aceptar");
            lugarEntry.Focus();
            return;
        }


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lugarEntry.Text))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Debe Ingresar un Lugar", "Aceptar");
            lugarEntry.Focus();
            return;
        }

        waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

        var infraccion = new Infraccion
        {               
            FechaInfraccion = fechaDatePicker.Date,              
            Motivo = motivoEntry.Text,
            PatenteAuto = patenteEntry.Text,
            LugarInfraccion = lugarEntry.Text,             
            MarcaAuto = marcaEntry.Text,
            ModeloAuto = modeloEntry.Text,
            RutInfractor = rutEntry.Text,
            Observacion = observacionEntry.Text,
        };


        //serializar el objeto infraccion
        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infraccion);

        //codificamos el objeto infraccion y lo guardamos en una variable content
        var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");

        string result;
        try
        {                
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://200.27.70.5/web_sit");
            string url = string.Format("/api/InfraccionsAPI", content);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "No se encuentra la Conexion", "Aceptar");
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            return;
        }

        waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
        await DisplayAlert("Confirmacion", "Infraccion correctamente creada!", "Aceptar");
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new InfraccionPage(usuarios));

    }                
}}
```

Comment: You need to take a look at what happens in the backend when the request is received. What is the response supposed to be like for a POST to the API that doesn't succeed in creating a DB entry vs. a successful one?

Comment: My InfraccionsAPI (BACKEND) is:


        // POST: api/InfraccionsAPI
        [ResponseType(typeof(Infraccion))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostInfraccion(Infraccion infraccion)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Infraccion.Add(infraccion);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = infraccion.IdInfraccion }, infraccion);
        }

Comment: What is the return value of `CreatedAtRoute` and does it match what you'd expect for a successful/unsuccessful db insertion?